# Recently my speedtest-cli only runs as sudo not root?

Tags: shell-script, cron

This has worked in my script for years but now something is goingon.

I can run sudo speedtest-cli as any user and it work.

As root if I use in cron or execute under root I get this error:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration
ERROR: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Any clue, really just need it to run under a cron job in my script.

Ubuntu 20 LTS - updated.

Speedtest.net is a speedtest utility.

The issue is for some reason the permissions from cron to my script is preventing this from running.

Comment: not sure if this is appropriate but in my script I added sudo speedtest-cli and that worked.

Comment: but have to add it to the root crontab not the user????

Comment: No one knows what `speedtest-cli` is. Please don't add new info as comments, instead edit your question.

Comment: What OS is this? Can you curl speedtest.net and get results back?